# Using Git with multiple servers

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitflow

I want to use a gitflow-like workflow, but with two servers. That is, regular work happens on server A and the release branch is hosted on server B, from where the release tags are created. Commits to server B should only happen when a new version is ready.

So, the question is: how can this be done, preferably with the GIT interface from within visual studio and without resorting to commandline tools?

Comment: What's the benefit of this arrangement?

Comment: Mostly personal preference, I suppose, but for the sake of argument server b might not be reachable all the time or might only allow certain users or one might want to keep as little changes on server b to facilitate audits...

Answer (score 1):

As git is a distributed revision control system it certainly allows you to do so, git-flow is just a set of scripts - more like an agreement on how some phases should be approached, so also for that you should be ok.
You should check the documentation about [remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes), this is a small abstract:

*To be able to collaborate on any Git project, you need to know how to manage your remote repositories. Remote repositories are versions of your project that are hosted on the Internet or network somewhere. You can have several of them, each of which generally is either read-only or read/write for you...*

...and see if there is some visual studio command to use different remotes.